# Method needed to generate "Sparkle-Paint" textures in Blender 2.68

Tags: textures, nodes, blender

Can someone advise me on how to construct a well-formed "sparkle-paint" shader?

Using nodes and (probably) image-maps in Blender, using CYCLES render! Also, preferably ***with*** "Z-axis displacement" (***unlike*** a plain bump-map...which is not realistic when viewed "from the side" on curved surfaces!)

Useful, [***IF*** variations in parameters can be "tweaked", ie. reflectivity, specularity, colours/sizes/shapes of the "grains"/"lumps"/"flakes", etc.]--for a variety of uses in *other* Blender scenes...

--T.I.A. for any answers to this! :o)

Answer (score 0):

i am not quiet sure what you mean by sparkle paint, but there is an example for car paint here
http://www.blendernation.com/2012/03/30/car-paint-shader-with-flakes-for-cycles/node/
and another one which is not made with cycles, but I guess you can figure out how to transform it to cycles 
http://matrep.parastudios.de/download.php?mat=294

Answer (score 0):

The surface deformation is best achieved by using a displace modifier. It displaces existing geometry so be sure to have enough, a subsurf modifier before the displace can help.